How important is Waterdeep: Dragon Heist to the story of Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage?
I want to run the adventure Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage, but my players usually don't like playing characters below level 5. Since Waterdeep: Dragon Heist is the lead in to the Mad Mage and gets to level 5, I was curious if anyone knows how important it is to play the other campaign?

Is Dragon Heist actually meant to be the lead in to Dungeon of the Mad Mage?

According to the wiki, yes? "It is the first part of the Waterdeep storyline and followed by a second adventure, Waterdeep: Dungeon of the Mad Mage." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterdeep:_Dragon_Heist

These two campaigns use the same location but overlap very little
Both campaigns are set in Waterdeep, so there may be some overlap in that players will become familiar with NPCs and locations in the city. Dragon Heist requires the players explore the city and interact with its inhabitants. Players are intended to build reputation with various factions and NPC to complete the campaign.
DotMM picks up a new storyline and is an extensive dungeon crawl beneath Waterdeep. Players in this campaign may spend very little time in the city proper. Inside knowledge of Waterdeep, reputation with NPCs, and revealed lore from the Dragon Heist campaign will do little to help a party in DotMM, without significant extra work for the DM. Also, there is little DotMM does to advance the story presented in Dragon Heist.
The campaigns fit well together to develop characters from level 1 to 20
Dragon Heist is designed to take characters from level 1 to 5. DotMM starts at level 5 and generally takes characters to somewhere close to level 20. These campaigns occur in the same place, with some overlapping settings. If you want to run a level 1 to 20 campaign, these are a good combination and don't require players to suspend disbelief as you transition between packaged campaigns.
TL;DR;
The plotlines of these campaigns have little beyond the setting in common. Each of these could be run independently without the players "missing" something from the other campaign. The big reason they are run back-to-back (as I'm planning to do in my next campaign) is that characters can seamlessly progress from one campaign to the next.

Good answer.  You might consider improving it by adding references.  For instance, have you played both of these modules?  Are you basing what you're saying from reading the adventures, or maybe 3rd party reviews?

They are separate stories that don't really have much to do with each other apart from "Waterdeep" in the name
Dragon Heist is an urban treasure hunt all throughout Waterdeep that focuses on exploring the city while Dungeon of the Mad Mage is a dungeon crawl that takes place in a huge dungeon that is canonically set underneath Waterdeep but could really be moved anywhere else without too much impact for the campaign since the city proper doesn't feature in it a lot. There is overlap in certain locations and NPCs the players might come across but the stories are completely separate and don't cross over.
They're often run together because they're set sort of in the same location and Dragon Heist covers levels 1-5, while Mad Mage goes from 5 to 20 so they can be combined relatively easily into a large 1-20 campaign. Both work perfectly fine as stand-alone campaigns though.

Good answer.  You might consider improving it by adding references.  For instance, have you played both of these modules?  Are you basing what you're saying from reading the adventures, or maybe 3rd party reviews?

@Jack I ran Dragon Heist from twice for different groups and started Mad Mage with one of these, we got to roughly halfway through

I think your answer would be improved by including what you wrote in the comment.  Answers based on experience help make great answers.  For instance, both campaigns feature Durnan and the Yawning Portal.  You might include whether or not that mattered in your experience.
